# Javascript: Date.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0) turns the date back one day?

Tags: javascript, date

Okay, this is bizarre. I've got this Date object:

2015-10-13T00:00:00.000Z

I call this function:

date.setHours(12, 0, 0, 0);

...and I get get back this:

2015-10-12T19:00:00.000Z

Why in the world would that be happening?

Comment: `.setHours()` uses your (or the user's) local time zone while the `Z` in the output represents [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Try [`.setUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours).

Comment: See [JavaScript setUTCHours returns wrong day](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23281932/1529630) and [Javascript date object always one day off?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7556591/1529630)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this kind of problem once, though [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setutchours.asp) helped me.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(15);
```

result:

> Sat May 23 2015 20:03:43 GMT+0500 (PKT)