# Javascript Date.UTC() returns previous day

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have the following method implemented for the date picker.

```
getMyDate: function(date){
  var year = date.find('.year').val(); // fetch the selected date from picker
  var day = date.find('.day').val();
  var month = date.find('month').val()-1;

  return new Date(Date.UTC(year,month,day)); // This is always returning previous day
}
```

Can someone tell me how to get the correct date based on the picker selection?

Comment: Why are you subtracting -1 from day?

Comment: is it because you are doing `var day = date.find('.day').val()-1;`? why not just `var day = date.find('.day').val();`? Also, months in JavaScript are zero indexed.

Comment: Sorry, thats my mistake while typing. Its a month and not day. I have updated my code.

Comment: Is your date picker displaying the date as a local date instead of a UTC date? If the year-month-day combination represents a local date, you should  use `new Date(year, month, day)`. If it represents a UTC date, you should look for an option to make your date picker act accordingly.

Comment: In my HTMl, I have dropdown datepicker and the values are set as month(january-december), year(2015 to 2020), and day (1-31) respectively. Even If you get the current date. Even if you try with hardcoded date, it returns the previous day something like below: alert(new Date(Date.UTC(2020,06,10)); // Returns wrong date

Comment: Well what is your timezone?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281932/javascript-setutchours-returns-wrong-day?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UTC() method returns the number of milliseconds between a specified date and midnight of January 1, 1970, according to **universal time**.
I think the reason of your issue is timezone.
So, please change the date with your timezone.

Please check following example

```
var offset = -8;
new Date( Date.UTC(2020, 1, 8) + offset * 3600 * 1000).toUTCString().replace( / GMT$/, "" )

"Fri, 07 Feb 2020 16:00:00"

var offset = +8;
new Date( Date.UTC(2020, 1, 8) + offset * 3600 * 1000).toUTCString().replace( / GMT$/, "" )
"Sat, 08 Feb 2020 08:00:00"
```